# QGIS: Scratch Layer Tools not showing up on my page evem the new ones that I open

Tags: qgis, layers, mapping

When I press the scratch layer tab, the pen that allows me to create the polygons do not show up. IDK what I pressed but now it won't show up anywhere else when I do a new project. Newb needs help

Comment: Check `View > Toolbars > Digitizing Toolbar` to see if it has been deactivated